# Delete specified rows by indices from a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a long list of dicts as my dataset (each row in the list is a dictionary).

There are a few rows in this list that I need to remove (because the data in these rows is inconsistent with the rest of the dataset).

I have already created a function that identifies the index numbers of the rows I would like to remove like so:

```
indices_to_remove = [10200, 15006, 22833, 33442, 54214]
```

I would like to have a function that deletes/removes all of the rows in my list if their index matches this list.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
my_original_dataset = *a list of dicts*

indices_to_remove = [10200, 15006, 22833, 33442, 54214]

def remove_missing_rows(dataset):
    new_list = []
    for row_dict in dataset:
        if row_dict not in indices_to_remove:
            new_list.append(row_dict)
    return new_list

new_dataset_all_empty_removed = remove_missing_rows(my_original_dataset)
```

I realize that the problem is that row_dict is referring to the actual row and not the index number of the row, but don't know how to reference to row number here.

Comment: You say you want to remove elements, but in your code you create a new list instead. What do you really want to do?

Comment: Why don't you do that while computing the indices?

Comment: If a row in my list has an index number matching the integer in my indices_to_remove list, I want to delete that row.

Comment: @dcg You said: "Why don't you do that while computing the indices?" I don't know how to do that. Here is the code for identifying the rows missing_id_vals = [i for i, a in enumerate(my_original_dataset) if not a.get("id", False)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the indices alongside the rows themselves with `enumerate`. Another thing to speed up the look up time of each index is to make the *list of indices* a set; sets are optimized for membership checks:

```
indices_to_remove = {10200, 15006, 22833, 33442, 54214}

def remove_missing_rows(dataset):
    new_list = []
    for i, row_dict in enumerate(dataset):
        if i not in indices_to_remove:
            new_list.append(row_dict)
    return new_list
```

You could also do this *flatly* using a list comprehension, without having to create a function:

```
new_list = [x for i, x in enumerate(dataset) if i not in indices_to_remove]
```

This creates a new list with all items in `indices_to_remove` dropped.

Comment: Or use a list comprehension: `[d for i, d in enumerate(dataset) if i not in to_remove]`. However, neither _removes_ indices, it creates a new list.

Comment: This works, thanks! Any pointers on learning how to use enumerate? I haven't really absorbed how he enumerate function works.

Comment: Typo: `if i not in:` ;)

Comment: @ThomasErnste Check the docs: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 0):

to literally remove from the dataset, `dataset.pop(i)` works

you have to `pop` from the end to the start so the `indices_to_remove` need to be sorted or you have to do it explictly

```
dataset = [1,2,3,4,5]
indices_to_remove = [1,3]

[dataset.pop(i) for i in indices_to_remove[::-1]]

dataset

Out[195]: [1, 3, 5]
```

the output of the listcomp can be ignored - all you want is the 'side effect' of removing the rows from the list

as sugested:

```
for i in indices_to_remove[::-1]:
    dataset.pop(i)
```

may be 'cleaner'

Comment: Note that this is quadratic in the worst case.

Comment: not necessarily a problem for _"There are a few rows in this list that I need to remove"_

Comment: Using list comprehensions for their side effects has some code-smell. Better use a normal loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of this
   'if row_dict not in indices_to_remove:' in 8th line of code
This will do the removal 
   'if dataset.index(row_dict) not in indices_to_remove:'